# Testing convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\cos{\log{n}}}{n \cdot \log{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Does the series:  $$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\log{n})}{n \cdot \log{n}}$$ converge or diverge?

I know that $|\cos(\log{n})| \leq 1$, but I really cannot apply it here. Any ideas on how to attack this problem

Comment: A quick try using $|\cos(\log{n})| \leq 1$ and the integral test gives that the $n$th partial sum is $\leq log(log(n))$, so if this diverges it does so very slowly.

Comment: On the other hand, the positive and negative terms "should" cancel each other out for the most part. I expect convergence.

Comment: I expect it to converge... Probably try a variation of generalized alternate test (Dirichlet test)?

Comment: A numerical value of the sum is in https://oeis.org/A363677 .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This problem appears in the Nordic university-level mathematics team-competition, NMC, 2010, with solution at the beginning of the following pdf: http://cc.oulu.fi/~phasto/competition/2010/solutions2010.pdf.

The search was `series "cos(log(n))"`.

Comment: And just for the record: the answer is that the series converges.

Answer (score 2):

In case the link Jonas gave would be broken in the future, here is the solution:

[image]
[image]