# series $\sum_2^\infty\cos( \log n)/n\log n$ converges or diverges??

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to know the series $\sum_2^\infty\cos( \log n)/n\log n$ converges or diverges. The log n in the bottom makes every my effort futile....Could anyone please help?

Comment: But you also have an $n$ in the bottom, which means maybe the integral test with a $u$-substitution?

Comment: then I cannot tackle with the $\cos( \log n)$...Could you please explain in more detail? I am just stuck and frustrated.....

Comment: The integral test doesn't work here because $cos(t)/t$ is not a positive valued function....

Comment: Ah, you're right about $\cos(t)/t$.  Hm...

Comment: I came to think that if I can show the partial sums of $\cos(\log n)/n$ are bounded, I can use the Dirichlet test.

Comment: This should help https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/936526/does-sum-n-1-infty-frac-cos-lnnn-converge with the bounded part of your question

Comment: @Keith:  Unlike what is stated in most textbooks, the integral test applies in that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$ and the integral $\int_1^\infty f(x) \, dx$ converge and diverge together if $\int_1^\infty |f'(x)| \, dx < \infty$. This is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2068845/148510).

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information...